# xv6 rev6 page fault handler

Tags: c, unix, assembly, operating-system, x86

I can't find the page fault handler in xv6-rev6 source code. Is it I missed it or there is no page fault handler at all? I do acctually found " #define T_PGFLT         14      // page fault " in Traps.h (line 2817 on the sheet), but I can't find it anywhere except in line 2817.

Answer (score 2):

The exception handling starts in `vector14()`, which is defined in vector.S, which is generated by [this Perl script](http://code.google.com/p/xv6-vm/source/browse/trunk/vectors.pl).

`vector14()` then transfers control to [`alltraps()`](http://code.google.com/p/xv6-vm/source/browse/trunk/trapasm.S), which is a common entry point for all further exception and system call handling.

`alltraps()` finally calls a C handler, [`trap()`](http://code.google.com/p/xv6-vm/source/browse/trunk/trap.c), which analyzes the event and dispatches the appropriate handler (system call, I/O, exceptions).

`trap()` calls [`pgfault_handler()`](http://code.google.com/p/xv6-vm/source/browse/trunk/proc.c) to handle page faults.